# Self-injecting java agent

Tags: java, agent

I am trying to create a self-injecting java agent. The agent and the code to dynamically load the agent would be contained in the same jar file.

I tried to do this by defining both `Main-Class` and `Agent-Class` in the manifest file. This is the file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: myjar.injector
Agent-Class: myjar.agent
```

However, I get the following error when I run the jar:
`com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Agent JAR not found or no Agent-Class attribute`

When I inspected the compiled jar, there was only a `Main-Class` attribute in the jar's manifest file. I tried recompiling outside of my IDE, but there was still only the `Main-Class` attribute.

Is there any way to have both `Main-Class` and `Agent-Class` in a jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just put it there. You have some process that turns java source files into a jar file. I would hope it is maven or gradle or some other build system. It might be an IDE or a handrolled script. There's nothing magical about it: Your tool chain is messing this up.

You can always check the manifest as follows:

```
jar xvf myjar.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: I built the jar using the `jar` command line utility. My manifest file initially contained both, but the jar's manifest only has `Main-Class`.

Comment: If you used `jar` with the `-m`, then that is impossible; you must have manually removed that line from the manifest you provided with the -m option, or you're not looking at the jar file you built.

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot, I was using the `jar` command wrong.